# Nested aggregate functions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(SYSDATE - inv_date)) FROM invoice;
```

What's wrong with this query?

Avg returns single value no
Max requires a group  to work on so it dosent execute and give error?
Please explain working
It's a quiz question according to which it won't execute I want to know the reason why it dosent execute I can't figure it out nested aggregate functions are allowed right?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Oracle allows nested aggregation functions (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm)).

However, it requires a `GROUP BY`.  So this is allowed:

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(SYSDATE - inv_date))
FROM invoice
GROUP BY Cust_ID;
```

Basically, this is a short-cut for:

```
SELECT MAX(x)
FROM (SELECT AVG(SYSDATE - inv_date) as x
      FROM invoice
       GROUP BY Cust_Id
     ) i;
```

In your case, though, there is no `GROUP BY`.  Oracle doesn't allow nested `GROUP BY` without the `GROUP BY`.

And if you are curious, I'm not a fan of this extended functionality.  I don't see that it actually solves a problem.

Comment: in the quiz they said this won't execute or throw error . I want to know the reason why it throws error.   SELECT MAX(AVG(SYSDATE - inv_date)) FROM invoice;

Comment: @MushkanTisekar . . . I elaborated.  I hadn't tried a nested `GROUP BY` without a `GROUP BY`.  Seems a bit odd to me that it *doesn't* work, but it generates a syntax error without the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: By the way could u tell me about the "FROM(.....)   i "                        
 can we use a variable like this ? U have used in your explanation query . I am a beginner in SQL so I don't know many things.

Comment: @MushkanTisekar . . . The is properly called a table alias.